# List elements are null just after adding them

Tags: c#, arrays, list, unity-game-engine

I have an unusual problem with my List. The code looks like this:

```
tanks = new List<Tank>();

tanks.Add(new Tank("Player", position1, false));
tanks.Add(new Tank("Enemy", position2, true));

if (tanks[0] == null) Debug.LogError("tanks[0] == null");
```

For some reason the error appears. Why does it happen? If I call List.Count, it returns 2... Can someone help me?

Comment: That is all you have for sure? You don't have an extra line between the if statement and the debug? I asked because you don't use  {} after your if so if you have an extra line in between, it will be skipped and your debug gets printed regardless the result of the check.

Comment: There's nothing between those lines, except some instructions that create other lists.

Answer (score 1):

As we can see on [this example](http://rextester.com/BVVI25690) your code works perfectly. This means that the code you provided does not have the error you talk about.

What is most definitely happening is what @Everts talked about in the comments, your `Debug.LogError("tanks[0] == null");` line is probably not within the `if` block in your code. Try adding brackets `{}`around it.

here is your updated code

```
tanks = new List<Tank>();

tanks.Add(new Tank("Player", position1, false));
tanks.Add(new Tank("Enemy", position2, true));

if (tanks[0] == null) 
{
    Debug.LogError("tanks[0] == null"); 
}
```

Comment: I think that it might be Unity issue. I know that the code should work, but it still doesn't.

Comment: can you show us the whole function ? Copy/pasted directly from your IDE ? I can't believe unity and whatever compiler it uses could fail at something as simple as a null check ...

Comment: Actually, I commented everything except those 4 lines in the function, and the error is even more weird now - it shows that the list is a null reference, although it's created in the line before.

Comment: uh ... it's getting even weirder -_- Can you give us a screenshot ? Your code sounds fun ;-)

Comment: Of course, I will upload them asap and post there

Comment: My bad, the null reference wasnt refering to the list, but to the argument that was not initialized. I uncommented one line that initializes it, and the error is still the same as in the beginning

Comment: What are the lines ? Is your "if" on the line 30 ? if you put a break point right before the if is hit (so on the if's line) and that you inspect the tanks var ?

Comment: Mind giving an updated screenshot ? What's the line that you uncommented ? Was it sown in the screenshot ?

Comment: I have found the problem.  I will never disable warnings since now xD One of them was saying: Creating a Monobehaviour by ,,new" keywoard is not allowed. Everything is clear now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: haha ! Glad i could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

For people who might have the same issue: creating Monobehaviours using ,,new" keyword is not allowed and it will cause an error. Just enable your warnings ;)

Comment: This is why it is also necessary to post your class too. Read the duplicate for more info on this